# Parsing a datetime string to date in Predicate using Java Time

Tags: java-8, datetime-format

There is a string field in a CSV file with the following format: **2008-04-11 00:00:00**

I need to convert it to date so that I can perform the following calculation in Predicate, to verify date typing errors.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
Predicate<Client> clientBirth = p -> Period.between(LocalDate.parse(p.getBirth().replaceAll("-", "/"), formatter),LocalDate.now()).getYears() >= 100;
```

But it's giving an error in the first line of the CSV file.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2008/04/11 00:00:00' could not be parsed at index 2
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2046)
at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1948)
at java.base/java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:428)
at application.Program.lambda$0(Program.java:210)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:176)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
at java.base/java.util.stream.SliceOps$1$1.accept(SliceOps.java:199)
at java.base/java.nio.file.FileChannelLinesSpliterator.forEachRemaining(FileChannelLinesSpliterator.java:114)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
at services.CsvProcessingService.loadBirthError(CsvProcessingService.java:123)
at services.CsvProcessingService.processBirthError(CsvProcessingService.java:109)
at application.Program.main(Program.java:214)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your DateFormat is `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` not `dd/MM/yyy`

Comment: BTW: post stacktraces as text not as image

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java string to date conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion)

Comment: @Jens   Hi Jens. Thank you for your reply. I need the date in following format: 11/04/2008.

Comment: Than you have to parse the date and format it in the new way. Mean you need 2 DateFormatter

Comment: @AdalbertoJoséBrasaca You have to accept reality. The string in the CSV file is `2008/04/11 00:00:00`, so you must change the software to parse that format. It will never work the other way round.

Comment: @Jens I thought I could change the date format and presentation. But since it's just for calculation, it worked... Thank you.

Comment: @Holger I thought I could change the date format and presentation. But since it's just for calculation, it worked... Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
```

use above as your date-time format from CSV is `2008-04-11 00:00:00` not `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Hi Vishwa... Thank you for your reply. I need the format of date from this ==> 2008-04-11 00:00:00 to this ==> 11/04/2008.

Comment: Du not suggest the old `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: @VishwaRatna I used only the first part ("yyyy-MM-dd") and the calculation worked... Thank you.

Comment: @VishwaRatna Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`. Also your code does nothing to format into a desired format.